# Why doesn't the JButton added to the DefaultTreeCellRenderer display?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I write a subclass of DefaultTreeCellRenderer, inside the method `getTreeCellRendererComponent`, I added a JButton to the `DefaultTreeCellRenderer` Object, I'd like to see each node of the JTree have a JButton rendered. but the JButton does not display, please see the code and screenshot. Thanks in advance!

```java
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeCellRenderer;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class TreeDemo{
    TreeDemo(){
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("TreeDemo");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode = initNodes();
        JTree jTree = new JTree(rootNode);
        jTree.setCellRenderer(new CustomRenderer());
        jFrame.getContentPane().add(jTree);
        jFrame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    DefaultMutableTreeNode initNodes(){
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("root");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode sub1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("sub1");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode sub2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("sub1");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode sub1_1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("sub1_1");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode sub1_2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("sub1_2");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode sub2_1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("sub2_1");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode sub2_2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("sub2_2");
        root.add(sub1);
        root.add(sub2);
        sub1.add(sub1_1);
        sub1.add(sub1_2);
        sub2.add(sub2_1);
        sub2.add(sub2_2);

        return root;
    }

    class CustomRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer{
        @Override
        public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean sel, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
            JButton button = new JButton("Button");
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(button, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
            setText("Node");

            return this;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TreeDemo();
    }
}
```

[Screenshot of the result of the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zwpr.png)

Comment: *"I'd like to see each node of the JTree have a JButton rendered"* Why? And what is supposed to happen when the user activates the button? See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: `DefaultTreeCellRenderer` is (an extension of) a `JLabel` - not intended to receive and display buttons (BTW `getComponent` can be called a lot of times - each cell when updating the tree - lot of buttons being created)

Answer (score 0):

Event though `JLabel` extends `java.awt.Container`, I don't think you can use it like a `JPanel`.

A tree cell renderer must implement interface `javax.swing.tree.TreeCellRenderer`. It doesn't need to extend `DefaultTreeCellRenderer`. Also note that `JTree` will use the same renderer instance to render all the tree nodes.

The below code is your code, but with a different tree cell renderer. It creates a single `JButton` and that button is displayed for every tree node.

```java
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeCellRenderer;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class TreeDemo{
    TreeDemo(){
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("TreeDemo");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode = initNodes();
        JTree jTree = new JTree(rootNode);
        jTree.setCellRenderer(new ButtonRenderer());
        jFrame.getContentPane().add(jTree);
        jFrame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    DefaultMutableTreeNode initNodes(){
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("root");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode sub1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("sub1");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode sub2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("sub1");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode sub1_1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("sub1_1");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode sub1_2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("sub1_2");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode sub2_1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("sub2_1");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode sub2_2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("sub2_2");
        root.add(sub1);
        root.add(sub2);
        sub1.add(sub1_1);
        sub1.add(sub1_2);
        sub2.add(sub2_1);
        sub2.add(sub2_2);

        return root;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TreeDemo();
    }
}

class ButtonRenderer implements TreeCellRenderer {
    private JButton  button;

    public ButtonRenderer() {
        button = new JButton("Button");
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree    tree,
                                                  Object   value,
                                                  boolean  selected,
                                                  boolean  expanded,
                                                  boolean  leaf,
                                                  int      row,
                                                  boolean  hasFocus) {
        return button;
    }
}
```

And here is a screen shot of the running application...

[image: tree demo]